# position absolute does not show all content, shown behind other components

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a custom dropdown but I have a problem with position absolute, does not show the entire contents of the menu shown only one part and the rest behind components.
[image: dropdown only show part of the menu]

```
.drop {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
}
.drop-down-menu {
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.drop-down-menu.show {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 136px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Try to correct the error with z-index but get no result
The drop-down-menu.show is added with javascript and not with Hover
this is the HTML code

```
<nav class="drop">
        <select name="drop-down">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <option value="">Option 1</option>
          <option value="">Option 2</option>
        </select>
      </nav>
```

I have run the application at this address:
https://showcase-douglascamposh.c9.io/
is: Drop-down list
I dont know what is the problem, whats is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
.row .column {
    /* ... */
    overflow: hidden;
    /* ... */
}
```

in your `jala-ui-framework.css` file so anything within the `.column` class that exceeds the height will be hidden. Remove that

Answer (score 3):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from the parent div with the `.column` class

```html
<div class="column xs-12">
  ...
  <ul class="drop-down-menu">
    <li data-option="">Select</li>
    <li data-option="">Option 1</li>
    <li data-option="">Option 2</li>
    <li data-option="">Option 3</li>
    <li data-option="">Option 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `overflow` is on the `.column` class, not `.xs-12`